# How to make radio button as square in ms word

Tags: microsoft-word, forms

I can see that the option button is round in MS word (active x control). I would like to create the option button in checkbox style or the checkboxes in option button style. To be clear, let assume I have Yes and No option and I want an user can select either Yes or No but that will be checkbox style instead round radio button. I can see this can be accomplished in pdf but I can't see a way in MS word Active X control.

Is there any way to accomplish this in MS word?

Comment: What's wrong with using a single checkbox, ticked is yes and unticked is no? That's how check boxes are supposed to work. Using radio buttons is the wrong thing for you to use.

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks for your answer. But the checkboxes do not work as radio button. A user can check both Yes and No, but that shouldn't be in my case. The user can either select Yes or No option, not both Yes or No at the same time. I have tried to put the same group name for both the Yes and No checkboxes, but did not work. They even can be checked both. Is there any other way to select either Yes or No by checkboxes? –

Answer (score 2):

The only way I have been able to work around this is to add check boxes and a bit of VBA to the word document. When I select one check box it clears all the other check boxes. I set up two check boxes, one called chkYes and the other chkNo. Then I added this code in the VBA editor. You should be able to just cut and paste it in. The first line chould end up in the (General) (Declarations). Enjoy.

Dim varInd As String

Private Sub chkYes_Click()

```
If varInd = "Running" Then Exit Sub
varInd = "Running"

chkNo.Value = 0
chkYes.Value = 1

varInd = ""
```

End Sub

Private Sub chkNo_Click()

```
If varInd = "Running" Then Exit Sub
varInd = "Running"

chkYes.Value = 0
chkNo.Value = 1

varInd = ""
```

End Sub

Answer (score 1):

ActiveX radio-button controls will always be a dot style. ActiveX checkbox controls will always be a tick. If you want different controls, you need to look at a 3rd party controls library. You can't edit the visual look of the ActiveX controls, only the behaviour of them.

If you must use a checkbox, bind unticked as 0 and ticked as 1.

e.g. a form where the question is

> Have you read the terms & conditions

Unticked means no, they have not.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the checkboxes do not work as radio button. A user can check both Yes and No, but that shouldn't be in my case. The user can either select Yes or No option, not both Yes or No at the same time. I have tried to put the same group name for both the Yes and No checkboxes, but did not work. They even can be checked both. Is there any other way to select either Yes or No by checkboxes?

Comment: They can't check both yes and no if you only have 1 checkbox. If you have multiple checkboxes on the same form, put them inside a frame to limit their behaviour.

Comment: would you tell me please Where can I get frame option and how to use it in order to control the checkboxes so that only one of them can be checked? I did not find any frame option in MS word 2010 activeX control of form.

Comment: On Controls click the bottom right icon (toolbox with a spanner) then More Controls (bottom right again). From the list of legacy controls choose Microsoft Forms 2.0 Frame. You'll then need to re-add your checkbox inside the frame (you have to draw it inside the frame, you can't drop it in over the top)

Comment: I can now add frame, but can't add checkboxes into it. The frame is non-editable, I can't draw checkboxes inside it. When I select frame and insert checkbox (now the checkbox of Active-X control is greyed out and only checkbox of Legacy Forms is enabled at this stage, so I have to add checkbox from the Legacy Forms actually), the the frame is gone automatically and a checkbox is showed but can't make them act like an option (either Yes or No can be selected only)

Comment: OK, I think it's time to go back to basics. Update your question with an image of what your document looks like, with the controls on.

Comment: Let's try finally before updating my question. I can now draw checkboxes inside frame. But they still behave like checkboxes. If I select both Yes or No, they can be selected both but I want only one of them can be select at time. If Yes is selected, then No will be deselected and if No is selected then Yes will be deselected automatically. Would you help me please in resolving this?

Comment: If you only want one, then you need to use 2 radio buttons instead.

Comment: that's the problem, I want radio button functionality but the appearance of radio button to be in square sized like checkboxes but can't find a way to combind them. In fillable pdf, I can change the radio button to square tick mark or can alter the functionality of checkboxes to radio button, so that only one checkbox can be selected from a group of checkboxes. Isn't there any such option in ms word?

Comment: And now we're back to my answer. No, there isn't without 3rd party controls.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110695/discussion-between-spikey-richie-and-abdullah-mamun-ur-rashid).